# "Sich bewerben um" oder "für"?

Tags: word-choice, verb, preposition, grammaticality

What is the correct version?

> - sich bewerben um etwas
> - sich bewerben für etwas

Are there cases where one or the other is preferable? Please make some examples if there are.

Comment: Both is acceptable, but *um* is preferable. Also possible: *auf* ;p

Comment: Hmm  - IMHO _für_ is hardly acceptable. Of course, you can use _"etwas bewerben"_ or _"für etwas werben"_. _"Für etwas bewerben"_ seems to mix up those two.

Comment: [Bewerben als](http://www.duden.de/shop/nachschlagen/duden-praxis-bewerben-als-akademiker-2/), [Bewerben für](http://www.duden.de/shop/nachschlagen/duden-praxis-bewerben-fur-die-ausbildung-1) and [Bewerben auf](http://www.staufenbiel.de/ratgeber-service/bewerbung/bewerben-auf-englisch.html)  (Yes, the last one is somehow different. Just kidding. But it is possible to say *bewerben auf eine Stelle*)

Comment: "Ich bewerbe mich für das Amt des Bürgermeisters/ des GL&U-Moderators"? Wie sonst? "Ich bewerbe mich als Bundeskanzler?" Klingt als sei ich es schon, was ja möglich ist: Man ist es, und möchte es wieder werden. "... um das Amt", ja richtig.

Comment: @Em1: "Bewerben für die Ausbildung" hat mich sehr überrascht; ich finde den Titel subjektiv nicht gerade gelungen. Man bewirbt sich um einen Ausbildungsplatz, und man stellt "für die Bewerbung" oder auch "für die Ausbildung" einen Ratgeber zu Verfügung. Der Titel "Bewerben für die Ausbildung" scheint mir (einmal mehr) beides zu vermischen. Für mich ist das Umgangssprache, also grammatisch nicht unbedingt korrekt, aber wohl üblich. Wenn sich jemand für eine Stelle bewerben würde, in der es auf korrekten Sprachgebrauch ankommt, würde die "für"-Variante einen dicken Minuspunkt bekommen.

Comment: @userunknown: Wie sonst? Ganz einfach: [_"um das Amt des Bürgermeisters"_](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bewerbe+mich+f%C3%BCr%2C+bewerbe+mich+um&year_start=1800&year_end=2012&corpus=8&smoothing=3).

Comment: @tohuwawohu Ich find's ehrlich gesagt OK. In vielen Dingen klingt "für" auch besser als "um". *Ich bewerbe mich für die Teilnahme an ...* ist 10x besser als *Ich bewerbe mich um die Teilnahme an ...*. Und nicht zuletzt, da das ein äußerst umstrittenes Thema ist (die Frage stellte sich schon vor vielen Jahren, nicht erst heute; aber DIE Antwort scheint nicht zu existieren), kann man jegliche Variante akzeptieren. Und wer einen dicken Minuspunkt verteilt, tja ... Pech. Ich würde es niemandem ankreiden. da sehe ich andere Dinge wichtiger an als die richtige Preposition  ... to be continued

Comment: Und Preposition ist ein wichtiges Stichwort. Es handelt sich hier nicht um eine Postposition zu bewerben. Also man darf die Frage der richtigen Wortwahl gar nicht abhängig von bewerben gestalten. Das ist als würde ich fragen: Heißt es "teilnehmen an" oder "teilnehmen in". Beides ist richtig.

Comment: @Em1: guter Hinweis!

Comment: Auch wenn ich prinzipiell ein minuspunktfreudiger Gesell bin - hier habe ich mich nicht um den Job als Buhmann beworben. ;)

Comment: @Em1 Aber heißen Präpositionen nicht so, weil sie *vor* ihrem Bezugswort stehen (also im vorliegenden Fall "Stelle", "Amt", "Position", etc.)? In der Regel sind das Nomen. Können Verben überhaupt Bezugswörter von Präpositionen (und Postpositionen) sein? Ich kenne es so, dass bestimmte Verben bestimmte Prä-/ Post-/ Circumpositionen erfordern, um die Beziehung zwischen Subjekt und Objekt auszudrücken. (Das können auch mehrere Verschiedene sein) Die Frage "Welche Präposition?" hängt also primär vom Verb ab. Sehe ich das falsch?

Comment: @Mac Du siehst es richtig. Aber es ist halt ein geläufiger Fehler, wie man hier in der Frage sieht, die Abhängigkeit zum falschen Bezugswort zu erschließen. Man kann natürlich zu jedem Verb "Postpositionen" bestimmen, die i.d.R. verwendet werden (bei bewerben haben wir alle aufgezählt), aber diese sind halt immer von Kontext entscheidend. Prinzipiell kann imho so eine Frage nur beantwortet werden, wenn auch ein Beispiel mitgeliefert wird, denn selbst "bewerben wegen" ist richtig.

Answer (score 11):

To not only comment but finally answer the question, there is quite a concise list of examples in [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/bewerben)

> - sich bei einer Firma bewerben
> - sich um eine Position, einen Job, eine Kandidatur, eine Nominierung, ein Amt, ein Mandat, ein Stipendium, einen Studienplatz, eine Mitgliedschaft bewerben
> - sich schriftlich, telefonisch, online bewerben
> - ich habe mich dort [als Managementassistentin] beworben
> - mehrere Bauunternehmen haben sich um den Auftrag beworben
> - er bewarb sich darum, in den Klub aufgenommen zu werden
> - (gehoben) sich um jemandes Gunst bewerben

They all show the usage of *"um"* as the preferred preposition used. Still, Duden says that it is not wrong to use *"auf"*. Anything else, especially *"für"* should not be used, even less so if it is in a letter of application. You may hear it in colloquial speech though.

Answer (score 1):

This question is already [answered by Takkat](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/4610/392), but i would like to add some Google NGram comparisons between the differen prepositions in connection with "bewerben":

### [bewarb mich für / bewarb mich um / bewarb mich auf](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bewarb%20mich%20f%C3%BCr%20,%20bewarb%20mich%20um%20,%20bewarb%20mich%20auf&year_start=1800&year_end=2012&corpus=8&smoothing=3)

[image: bewarb mich für,bewarb mich um,bewarb mich auf]

### [bewarb sich für / bewarb sich um / bewarb sich auf](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bewarb%20sich%20f%C3%BCr%20,%20bewarb%20sich%20um%20,%20bewarb%20sich%20auf&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3)

[image: bewarb sich für,bewarb sich um,bewarb sich auf]

### [bewirbt sich für / bewirbt sich um / bewirbt sich auf](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bewirbt%20sich%20f%C3%BCr%20,%20bewirbt%20sich%20um%20,%20bewirbt%20sich%20auf&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3)

[image: bewirbt sich für / bewirbt sich um / bewirbt sich auf]

### [bewerbe mich für / bewerbe mich um / bewerbe mich auf](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bewerbe%20mich%20f%C3%BCr%20,%20bewerbe%20mich%20um%20,%20bewerbe%20mich%20auf&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3)

[image: bewerbe mich für / bewerbe mich um / bewerbe mich auf]

At a first glance it seems that using "für" is a quite new trend, having gained a considerable currency even in written language. But there are cases of using "für" where other prepositions can't be used:

> "Er bewirbt sich **für** seine Partei um den Posten als...";
>
> "Sie bewirbt sich **für** den Bereich Marketing."

and so on. So, the counts for "auf" may indicate in such phrasing, not necessarily in "sich **für** einen Posten bewerben".

Comment: Warum redest du im Text von "auf", wenn die Beispiel mit "für" gebildet sind?

Comment: @Em1: Danke für den Hinweis - da hatte ich offenbar etwas den Überblick verloren. Ist korrigiert.

Comment: @tohuwawohu Ein zusätzliches Problem ist, dass Ngram nicht zwischen "bewirbt sich um die Stelle" und "bewirbt sich, um seinen Vater zu ärgern" unterscheiden kann. Vielleicht überall "die Stelle" anhängen?

Comment: @Phira - das Problem besteht grundsätzlich schon. Ich fürchte aber, das eine weitere Einschränkung zwar den "Recall", aber auch den "fallout" deutlich erhöht und das Ergebnis dann weniger wert ist als vorher. Bereits die ersten paar Google-Treffer haben neben "die Stelle" auch "eine" Stelle, dann "den Arbeitsplatz" oder schlicht "... bewerbe mich um etwas". Das wären alles positive Treffer, die so aussortiert werden würden. Da stößt die NGram-Suche einfach an ihre Grenzen.